# CSS background-attachment:fixed; issue in mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile, background, viewport

So, I'm having issues with a fixed background on mobile devices. When viewed in Chrome on my Windows 7 laptop, the background looks fine; the image (which is thin) tiles horizontally and stays fixed to the viewport. In Chrome on my Android phone, though, the background sticks to the top of the page, disappearing as a I scroll down.

Now, I already know these mobile browsers have a different idea of what a viewport is, and therefore `background-attachment:fixed;` will not work, but none of the solutions I find seem to fix anything (or maybe I'm just misunderstanding them). The general suggestion seems to be to apply a wrapper div to the page that holds the background instead, which I tried to do based on [this blog post](http://catch404.net/2012/12/fixed-backgrounds-on-the-bad-that-is-all-mobile-browsers/):

```css
#wrap {
background-image: url(../img.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left top;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%; /* sticky footer */
overflow-x: hidden; /* sticky footer */
}
```

This does not fix my problem at all; it just messes up the fixed appearance on the laptop. Is there something I'm not understanding? I'm very new to web coding (CSS/HTML), so I think there may be something I'm just missing here.

Comment: tried `<meta viewport>`? eg.: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean? I do have a viewport meta tag in the header, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: Yes, but the `<meta view-port>` is set equal to the scale to my example? That is to AutoAdjust?

Comment: It does not include `maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0`. Will this make a difference with respect to the code above?

Comment: I added it in; by itself, it doesn't seem to make any difference to the current code or the revised code given above.

Comment: Wait, AutoAdjust? What is that? (Sorry for all the newbie questions.)

Comment: *AutoAdjust* is a word and not a function (I mean content of the page fits the screen size of the mobile). `<meta viewport>` might make a difference. Add an example of your page online for those who read your question to see exactly what happens.

Comment: I went ahead and added the link to the site in the post, if you would like to check it out.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On **opera-mobile** worked perfectly. In **Safari iOS6** (Iphone) did not work (not sure if it's a browser crash or code).

I recommend to use this *iScroll4*:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

or iScroll5 (beta test):

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5-ready-for-beta-test